# React Context with Hooks is always "one step behind"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I am coding a computer comparison website and I encountered an issue when setting filters for the API call. It seems to always be "one step behind" when I add a filter. For example, I add the filter for "orderby" and then call `getComputers()`, which fetches the pcs from our api using the filters as parameters, but it doesn't apply any parameters, as the filters are still empty. If I do it again with a different value for "orderby" it takes the value from before as param for the api call. I don't understand why this works the way it does and would really appreciate any help :)

Yes, I did research on this before, but nothing seemed to work for me...

Here is my code:

The search results page:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import SearchContext from '../../context/search/SearchContext';
import Navbar from '../layout/Navbar';
import Computers from '../computer/Computers';
import Select from 'react-select';

const SearchResults = () => {
  const searchContext = useContext(SearchContext);
  const { filters, orders, getComputers, addFilter } = searchContext;

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar activeItem='Search'></Navbar>

      <div className='container my-3 text-dark'>
        <div className='row'>
          <div className='col-lg-9 col-md-6'>
            <h1 className='display-3 mt-3'>Suche</h1>
          </div>
          <div className='col-lg-3 col-md-6'>
            <Select
              placeholder='Sortierung'
              options={orders.map(order => {
                return { value: order.value, label: order.trans };
              })}
              onChange={val => {
                addFilter({ name: 'orderby', value: val.value });
                getComputers();
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='my-3'>
          {filters.map((filter, index) => {
            var text = filter.value.toString();
            return (
              <span
                className='badge badge-pill badge-secondary mx-1 p-2'
                key={index}
              >
                {text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1)}
              </span>
            );
          })}
        </div>

        <Computers></Computers>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchResults;
```

Strangely, my page displays the current "orderby" filter correctly in the little pills (see line 42). But the API call doesn't take the right filter...

Relevant parts of my Context:

SearchState.js:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(SearchReducer, initialState);

// ACTIONS

  // Add filter
  const addFilter = filter => {
    console.log(state.filters);
    dispatch({ type: ADD_FILTER, payload: filter });
  };

// Get PCs from API
  const getComputers = async () => {
    try {
      state.loading = true;
      console.log(state.filters);
      let params = {};
      state.filters.forEach(filter => {
        // if (filter.name !== 'usecase' && filter.name !== 'type')
        //only as long as usecase and type are not implemented in api yet
        if (!params[filter.name]) params[filter.name] = '';
        params[filter.name] = filter.value;
      });
      console.log(params);
      const res = await axios.get(
        'notgonnatellumyurlxd',
        {
          params
        }
      );
      console.log(res);
      dispatch({ type: GET_COMPUTERS, payload: res.data });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

SearchReducer.js:

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_FILTER:
      // Used for deciding whether to update existing filter or set new
      var update = false;
      state.filters.forEach(filter => {
        if (filter.name === action.payload.name) {
          update = true;
        }
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        filters: !update
          ? [...state.filters, action.payload]
          : state.filters.map(filter =>
              filter.name === action.payload.name ? action.payload : filter
            )
      };
.
.
.
case GET_COMPUTERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        computers: action.payload,
        loading: false
      };
};
```

I am really struggling with this right now and hope to find some help here. Big thanks in advance! You people on here are great :)

Comment: Can you create simpe exaple (not replicate your entyre app) on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) with Context and Context.Provider as well? I'd like to take a look into the issue, but will need to log values during various operations.

Comment: Thanks for you efforts, but the question was already answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getComputers` works on other `state` "instance"/ref`

You can use `useEffect` as `addFilter` changes `filter`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getComputers();
}, [filter]);

onChange={val => addFilter({ name: 'orderby', value: val.value })}
```

`addFilter` changes `filter` ... `filter` change runs effect code (every time it changes)

Comment: Biiiiig thanks! Works just as intended! Didn't know that React creates different state "branches" for different operations... Thank you for this great answer :)

Comment: it's similar to setState behaviour ... you can't expect updates just after command (without callbacks)